# Image bounds checking with unsigned numbers

Tags: c++, image-processing

I have an image represented by 2D matrix indexed by size_t. I wan't to have a function that you give a position and it returns if that position is inside the bounds of that image.

Where I would use such function, is f.e. in floodfill algorithm where I would after checking one pixel, push it's surrounding 4 pixels into the queue. Problem occurs if the pixel I'm checking is on 0 x or y which means the inBounds function would get called with (x - 1, y) and (x, y - 1). Because of size_t being unsigned I can't reasonably check if the x or y is < 0.

How can I deal with these situations? Should I just check for bottom and left bound and assume that if given position is above or to the right of image it will be huge number anyway?

Comment: Why not just use `int`?

Answer (score 1):

Just cast (static_cast) your `size_t` values to `signed int` every single time you use them in  operations that also involve signed ints.

Generally, it is not a good idea to mix signed and unsigned numbers.  Unsigned numbers are nothing but a hack that allows twice the range for the same number of bits, and just as any hack, they have caused, are causing, and will be causing innumerable problems to programmers all over the world.  That's why certain languages like java completely abolished them.  When I first moved from C++ to java I was really missing unsigned numbers, but after a while "I learned to stop worrying and love the bomb."